# Error: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types when running through for-loop VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, null

I have a problem with null value. I need an if to check if 2 values are null. If I loop through the For the first time, everything is fine. When I loop through the For the second time, I get an error on 'oTableTemp.Rows(i)("ProspectielijstId").ToString() = ""'. I have absolutly tried everything. I've tried DbNull.Value, Is Nothing,... 
This is the full code:

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To oTableTemp.Rows.Count - 1 Step 1

        If (Convert.ToInt32(oTableTemp.Rows(i)("OpleidingsId")) = 0 And oTableTemp.Rows(i)("ProspectielijstId").ToString() = "" And oTableTemp.Rows(i)("ActieId") = specialeactieId) Then
            cString &= "SELECT * FROM AITest..SpecialeActie WHERE SpecialeActie.ActieId = " + clGlobalsData.G_FieldN(specialeactieId)
            Exit For
        ElseIf (oTableTemp.Rows(i)("ProspectielijstId").ToString() IsNot "" And oTableTemp.Rows(i)("ActieId") = specialeactieId) Then
            cString &= "    SELECT KlantProspectAlgemeen.Nummer, SpecialeActie.Titel, SpecialeActie.Inhoud, SpecialeActie.Link " & _
            "FROM (AITest..SpecialeActie INNER JOIN AITest..t_ProspectieLijst ON t_ProspectieLijst.NaamLijst= " & _
            "SpecialeActie.ProspectielijstID) INNER JOIN AITest..KlantProspectAlgemeen ON t_ProspectieLijst.Nummer=KlantProspectAlgemeen.Nummer WHERE SpecialeActie.ActieId = " + clGlobalsData.G_FieldN(specialeactieId)
            Exit For
        ElseIf (Convert.ToInt32(oTableTemp.Rows(i)("OpleidingsId")) <> 0 And oTableTemp.Rows(i)("ActieId") = specialeactieId) Then
            cString &= "SELECT KlantProspectAlgemeen.Nummer, SpecialeActie.Titel, SpecialeActie.Inhoud, SpecialeActie.Link " & _
            "FROM (AITest..SpecialeActie INNER JOIN AITest..Cursus ON Cursus.NummerInternCursus=SpecialeActie.OpleidingsID " & _
            "INNER JOIN AITest..CursusEmailmarketing ON Cursus.NummerInternCursus = CursusEmailmarketing.NummerInternCursus " & _
            "INNER JOIN AITest..t_ProspectieLijst ON t_ProspectieLijst.NaamLijst=CursusEmailmarketing.ProspectielijstID) " & _
            "INNER JOIN AITest..KlantProspectAlgemeen ON t_ProspectieLijst.Nummer= KlantProspectAlgemeen.Nummer WHERE SpecialeActie.ActieId = " + clGlobalsData.G_FieldN(specialeactieId)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

Please help me, i'm desperate..

Answer (score 0):

First, i'm not sure what causes the error exactly, however, here are some general tips which can help to find the reason for the error and to fix it:

I suggest to use the `Field` extension method of `DataRow` which is strongly typed and also supports nullable types. It automatically converts `DBNull.Value` to the appropriate nullable type.

You should also use `AndAlso` instead of `And`. The former will not execute the second part if the first was already `False` whereas the latter will execute both always which can result in errors like this.

Consider this:

```
Dim str As String = Nothing
If str IsNot Nothing And str.Length = 0 Then
   ' boooom
End If
```

this works:

```
If str IsNot Nothing AndAlso str.Length = 0 Then
    ' no booom 
End If
```

Here the sql part to show you an example which is also more readable:

```
For Each row As DataRow In oTableTemp.Rows
    Dim OpleidingsId = row.Field(Of Int32)("OpleidingsId")
    Dim ProspectielijstId = row.Field(Of String)("ProspectielijstId")
    Dim ActieId = row.Field(Of Int32)("ActieId")

    If OpleidingsId = 0 AndAlso String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ProspectielijstId) AndAlso ActieId = specialeactieId Then
        cString = "SELECT * FROM AITest..SpecialeActie WHERE ..."
    End If
```

Note that you are also open for [**SQL-Injection**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), use SQL-Parameters!

Comment: The Exception still occures when i hit the if for the second time

Comment: Now he gives an exception on 'Dim OpleidingsId = row.Field(Of Int32)("OpleidingsId")'. This is the exception: Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Int32'. Please use a nullable type.

Comment: you can declare OpleidingsId as nullable. try Like Dim OpleidingsId? = row.Field(Of Int32)("OpleidingsId"). You might have to cast it to integer type im not sure, give it a try

Comment: @CharlotteVancraeynest: That's what i wanted to suggest above. Use nullable types when it's appropriate. I didnt know which column coukld be null. `Dim OpleidingsId = row.Field(Of Int32?)("OpleidingsId")` Now you can check `If OpleidingsId.HasValue Then Console.Write(OpleidingsId.Value)`